# iOS MobileMe Sync

Tags: iphone, data-synchronization, ios, mobileme

Hey does anyone know if there is a public framework to sync data between iOS devices using MobileMe?  I've tried googling it and have come up empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe that there is yet. Apple have a MobileMe SDK on the desktop, but haven't released anything for iOS as yet. And if memory serves, I can't recall having seen any iOS apps that use MobileMe for syncing, beyond the built-in Calendar, AddressBook and Notes apps.

Comment: Ya, that's was I though, too.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you could use MobileMe as a [WebDAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV) server to sync your data OTA.

This is, for example, what [Wallet](http://www.acrylicapps.com/wallet/) uses.